# How to write double value in cell with leading spaces using Apache POI and java

Tags: java, string, apache-poi

I want to write a `double` into cell with leading spaces.
**For example:** "      0.20"
before **0.20**  there should have 6 spaces.

**What i've tried** 
I tried with single inverted comma **(')** like this [**'      0.20**]
I was able to write value with 6 leading space, but **(')** also got written in the cell,
but I just want to write the value and not the **(')** with value.

**Code Used**:

`cell.setCellValue("'      0.20");`

Please help!.

Answer (score 3):

You do this just the same way as you would in Excel - with a custom cell number format

Firstly, if this is new to you, have a read of the [Microsoft Excel documentation on cell formattings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/264372/how-to-control-and-understand-settings-in-the-format-cells-dialog-box-in-excel). From that, you'll see that the possible ways to get 6 spaces in front of a #.## number is either

```
"      "0.00
```

or

```
_0_0_0_0_0_00.00
```

The former forces 6 blank spaces before the `0.00` number format, the latter forces 6 widths of the number `0` followed by the `0.00` number format.

The latter could be tweaked to use a `1` instead if that's more the gap you want with this:

```
_1_1_1_1_1_10.00
```

Then, to do that in Apache POI, you'd go for code something like:

```
// Do this only once, and re-use it
CellStyle csGap = wb.createCellStyle();
csGap.setDataFormat(
    workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("_0_0_0_0_0_00.00"));

// Create a new sheet and set A1 to 0.20
Sheet s = wb.createSheet();
Cell a1 = s.createRow(0).createCell(0);
a1.setCellValue(0.20);
a1.setCellStyle(csGap);
```

Comment: -What is createHelper variable. ?

Comment: Call [Workbook.getCreationHelper](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getCreationHelper())

Comment: @Gagravarr-
I tried your code,, now the value is entered ,but it's stored on the right side of the cell. Moreover there are no spaces before the decimal value

Comment: Try also setting the cell alignment to left? (I think that was the default for me when I tried it...) There won't be real spaces before the numbers though, this formatting just leaves a gap as if there were, just like in Excel!

Comment: -I tried  that ,and compared the code generated output with manual input , but it's not matching.
  
   "   0.20    "   0.20"  No match"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format` to add spaces to a string :

```
double myValue = 0.20;
String formatted = String.format("%10s",String.valueOf(myValue));
cell.setCellValue(formatted);
```

The `%` introduces a sequence, `10` is the total length of the new string, so this should add 6 white spaces in the beginning of your string.

Comment: Yeah that is working , but the moment i double click on the cell with 0.20 value, it moves to right side of the cell,leading to right alignment .I want it to place the value at it's place irrespective of any click on the cell.

Comment: This sounds like you want to change the cell alignment. You can use [`CellUtil`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) to specify the alignment of a cell. Try `CellUtil.setAlignment(cell,  HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);`

Comment: No, i don't want to set alignment ,I tried that.If I enter value with the center alignment , and i again double click on the cell with the value 0.20, then it will set to center alignment , which i don't want.I just want the spaces to remain there irrespective of the click on that cell.

Comment: Well , I can't help you with this one. This is a different question and I suggest asking it on Stack Overflow. I'm sure somebody will help you. Good luck!